# How to force 'Enter' key without user interaction in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox on a windows form (using visual studio 2008 - C#) that gets its data from a hand held scanner attached to the monitor. When the user scans a barcode the data gets inputted in the textbox and just sits there.

What I want to be able to do is somehow force an Enter/Return key stroke without the user pressing anything.

Is that even possible?

Comment: When you say "windows form" do you mean [Winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [webform](http://www.asp.net/web-forms)?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain its a windows form

Comment: Then why do you have `asp.net` tagged on your question?

Comment: Use one of the textbox change events to detect the entry and call the same method that the enter button causes to be called

Comment: @ScottChamberlain oh sorry my mistake

Comment: Where's the code that reads the barcode? Why can't you just do whatever you need to do there? Why is it even pushed to a textbox instead of just being processed? If you find yourself needing to fake a user interaction, you should take a step back and ask why you need the user interaction in the first place.

Comment: @AlexK. I tried using the TextChanged event but I causes the event to trigger for every character that gets sent to the textbox

Comment: @MattBurland that's how cheap scanners work: they emulate a keyboard, sending characters to a textbox

Comment: Is the end result of the scan a set number of characters? If so, do nothing until the length entered is correct, is the last character a control character? If so, detect that.

Comment: @hmakled: How do you propose to know when it's finished anyway so you could "fake" an enter? However you do that, do that in the `TextChanged` event instead.

Comment: @hmakled scanners that emulate keyboards can be configured to send an `Enter` key (or any other key) after the scanned characters. Check your scanner's manual for the correct settings/procedure. You may have to set DIP switches or scan specific codes from a configuration sheet

Comment: @AlexK. No its not a set number. It could change in length.

Comment: Presumably the `TextChanged` events fired when a code is scanned are fired very rapidly. Perhaps you could set a timer in the `TextChanged` event and if no other characters are received in, say, one second, then you can do whatever you need to do with the scanned code? Not the most robust solution, but might be workable.

Comment: @MattBurland thats the issue im having. I don't know when the input is finished.

Comment: @hmakled did you try configuring the scanner to send the `Enter` key?

Comment: @hmakled: "I don't know when the input is finished." then being able to fake an "enter" keystroke isn't going to help you. Not if you don't know *when* it needs to happen.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No I haven't I can look into that. Thats a possibility.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a programming solution if you can configure your scanner correctly.

Expensive scanners provide an API that allows you to configure the scanner and receive scan events directly. Cheaper scanners emulate the keyboard and send characters to whichever window has the focus.

Such scanners almost always allow configuration to set various scanning parameters, including prefix and suffix characters. You should be able to specify `Enter` as a suffix character following the procedure specified by the manufacturer.

You can also use a "weird" prefix character (eg §) to notify your form of a scan so that the end user doesn't have to place the focus on the text box. You can set the form's [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property to capture the keyboard events at the form level and set the focus to the Textbox programmatically, or start capturing all keys until you detect the `Enter` character.

Some scanners can be configured by setting DIP switches. Others can be configured by scanning special codes from a configuration sheet. The procedure varies by manufacturer and the type of scanner.

Comment: This answer reflects a similar answer given on SuperUser http://superuser.com/a/379063/45156 that has a few examples. Be sure to find the specific config barcodes for your specific model of scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Perform validation when the text box changes to determine if the scan is complete (it may register multiple change events).

Once complete, you can either call whatever processing function the Enter key would cause to be called, or insert carriage return+line feed characters if what you want is to move to another line.